# Why am I getting lesser connected components than actual for my graph using DFS?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I am trying to find a method `countVertices()` which needs to returns the number of vertices in the same connected component of the given vertex using DFS.

I am not able to understand why am I always getting 2 when there are 3 connected components (including parent) for my graph. It's going wrong for all of the tests I tried

My code for the method looks like this:

```
public static int countVertices(Graph g, Graph.Vertex v) {
    Set<Graph.Vertex> known = new HashSet<>();
    int num = 0;

    if(g == null || v == null)
        return 0;

    for(Graph.Vertex u : g.getAllVertices()) {
        if(!known.contains(u)) {
            num++;
            DFS(g, u, known);
        }
    }

    return num;
}

public static void DFS(Graph g, Graph.Vertex v, Set<Graph.Vertex> known) {
    known.add(v);

    for(Graph.Vertex vertex : g.getNeighbours(v)) {
        if(!known.contains(vertex))
            DFS(g, vertex, known);
    }
}
```

I tried the following in my `main()` method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
     Graph g = new Graph();
     Graph.Vertex v = new Graph.Vertex(1);
     Graph.Vertex w = new Graph.Vertex(2);
     Graph.Vertex x = new Graph.Vertex(3);
     Graph.Vertex y = new Graph.Vertex(4);

     g.addVertex(v);
     g.addVertex(w);
     g.addVertex(x);
     g.addVertex(y);
     g.addEdge(v, w);
     g.addEdge(w, y);

     System.out.println(countVertices(g, v)); // this outputs 2, it should be 3
     System.out.println(countVertices(g, x)); // this outputs 2, it should be 1
}
```

I am not able to figure out what am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help.

**Edit:**

```
public static int countVertices(Graph g, Graph.Vertex v) {
    Set<Graph.Vertex> known = new HashSet<>();
    int num = 1;

    if(g == null || v == null)
        return 0;

    //for(Graph.Vertex u : g.getNeighbours(v)) {
        if(!known.contains(v)) {
    num++;
    DFS(g, v, known);
        }
    //}

    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v-w and w-y are 2 edges that belong to the same component. x is the only isolated vertex. Therefore, the correct output is 2 connected components and not 3.

EDIT: If you remove either the edge between v-w OR w-y, you will have 3 connected components.

A method that I used recently is to check if two vertices have the same root. In your case, if we take v as the root then w is child to v and y is child to w => y is child to v and therefore is one component. x is a root vertex with no children therefore another component. I hope this gives some insight on connected components.

As for the number of vertices, your `int num = 0` should probably be `int num = 1`. This is because if the graph is not null, then the graph has **at least** one vertex.

```
// after a short discussion, we found the solution
// return the size of HashSet known
public static int countVertices(Graph g, Graph.Vertex v) {
    Set<Graph.Vertex> known = new HashSet<>();
    int num = 0;

    if(g == null || v == null)
        return 0;

    // no loop, call DFS method and it will call itself recursively
    // and it will call the get neighbors()    
    if(!known.contains(v)) {
        num++;
        DFS(g, v, known);
    }
    return known.size();
}
```

Comment: I think v-w-y all are connected and x is alone so for `countVertices(g,x)` it should be 1 and for others it should be 3. I am trying to count number of vertices.

Comment: i see, now i understand your question. However, there are only 2 connected components. You stated in your question that there were 3 connected components hence the confusion.

Comment: Also, you initialized `int num = 0` but if the graph is not null, that implies that it already has a vertex. This means that you should have `int num = 1` after the test for a graph being null or not. That is why you have one less vertex

Comment: I understand and I tried this, but the problem is after doing this it gives 3 for `countVertices(g,x)` too. And earlier for that it gave 2. So I was thinking maybe there is something wrong with my method.

Comment: just did a trace for your function, it seems to be working properly. Let me get this straight, you want to count the number of vertices in the given component? Am i correct? P.S. `int num = 1` will still be required.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Okay I totally understand and agree with num = 1 being required since null case has already been used. But I am not able to figure out what is going wrong with the x component, which should be 1 but gives 3.

Comment: Of course it will give 3, in fact, for both the function calls, the output will be 3. Since you are looping through all the vertices and not the one vertex you want to check the DFS for `g.getAllVertices()`..change to only do DFS on the one vertex you want to check, ie. no loop and call directly `DFS(g, v, known)`

Comment: yes that makes perfect sense and I edited my code to that, but now it gives correct for x but 2 for w and y. I am adding the edited code too

Comment: Ok, so you were not supposed to add the `v.getneighbors()`, i only edited your `countVertices` function and I removed the loop. Don't loop. Because the loop is being done in your DFS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191771/discussion-between-manhar-and-simptri).